# Firebase dynamic link not open in development app while app is not in appstore

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

My concern is as i have not upload on app store but when i click on deeplink url debug mode application is not open its redirect on Appstore

I AM ABLR to redirect on my debug application.

I am working on dynamic link objective c

as i have tested my app is configure fine in firebase

but when I am share my product with other user they tap on url its redirect on safari and link is not working

every time i have to copy the link and past into chrome and also here poup u comes like your app is open another application then redirect to app ...

I WANT THAT WHEN I CLICK ON LINK IT REDIRECT DIRECT ON APPLICATION RATHER THEN SAFARI OR MANUALLY COPY THAT LINK AND THEN OPENAPP

Note: application is not live i want to open url my debug application.

I have configure the application for getting appstoreid and teamid

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
      restorationHandler:

My link not working in safari but its working on chrome how  to manage to work on safari as well...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The options below are assumed that you created a Firebase project in any plan. If you don't have, check the docs

### Option 1: Open in browser to a website ([see source guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains))

> If you are using Cloudflare for DNS records management, please **DO NOT** proxy the origin IP addresses to the domain (or the subdomain) you wish to use **Dynamic Links** for your domain, as Google might not verify your domain because they don't use TXT verification as GitLab Pages does.

1. [Set up **Firebase Hosting** if you haven't done this after project creation](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/hosting/).
2. After setting up, open [**Dynamic Links**](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/durablelinks).

   - New to Dynamic Links? Click **Get started**. Otherwise, click **Add URL prefix**. You can only add up to 5 URL prefixes per project.

     > If you use a domain/subdomain for Hosting or Dynamic Links, you can't use it again for Dynamic Links and vice versa. Try link prefixes (for example, `demofirebaseproject.devhubcentral.ml/launchapp/insert-link-suffix-here`) or an special subdomain (for example, `demofirebaseproject.devhubcentral.ml/insert-link-suffix-here`) instead.
   - A setup wizard pops out. Type the domain you want to use and Google will show suggestions for you based on what you type.  Choose wisely, then click **Next**. In our example project ID `nomadic-bedrock-257008`, I use `demofirebaseproject.devhubcentral.ml` for this tutorial
   - Now, configure your options for the domain you want to use. The path prefix I use for the demo project is `/launchapp` because the devs at the Pins team want to use `demofirebaseporject.devhubcentral.ml/launchapp` to launch in the Pins' official app, but surely, this app will be available in App Store soon. For now, we redirect users to `contributors-program.recaptime.tk`. When ready, click **Next**.
   - Then, fire up your DNS provider and add `151.101.1.195` and `151.101.65.195` as A records for the domain/subdomain you use. In our demo project, I am using Cloudflare to manage DNS records for `devhubcentral.ml`, so I need to change **Proxy Status** to **DNS Only** for ownership checks. [See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA2pW.png) to see how I configured it. When done, click **Finish** and create your first Dynamic Link.

     > DNS propagation usually takes 24 hours or longer, but some DNS provider/domain registrars propagate DNS records sooner.
3. **For iOS only**: Open `Info.plist` file in your Xcode project and add the following code below. Replace sample strings into the ones for your project and add more strings as needed.

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
<array>
  <string>demofirebaseproject.devhubcentral.ml/launchapp</string>
</array>
```

> You add up to 10 prefixes per Firebase project. If you need more, remove prefixes that you don't use.

### Option 2: Try in your debug app (and share to your other devs for testing)

1. Open your Firebase project overview and Xcode project.
2. Click the plus icon then select an iOS icon.
3. Register your app's basic info.
4. Download the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file into your Xcode project root folder.
5. Open a terminal, use `pod init` if you don't have a Podfile. Edit it to add the below. Save it and then run `pod install` to generate a `.xcworkspace` for your project. Use this file for all future development on your application.

```
# add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
# add pods for any other desired Firebase products
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods
```

4. Add the init code to your app codebase using this below for Swift.

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
      [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
  }
}
```

> Have Objective-C project instead? Maybe use this code instead
>
> ```c
> @import UIKit;
> @import Firebase;
>
> @implementation AppDelegate
>
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
>    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
>  [FIRApp configure];
>  return YES;
> }
> ```

5. Run your app to verify the installation. If you don't have a project yet, skip this step and try again later.
6. Try option 1 above, but this time, we're using your iOS app for this one.

### Option 3: Publish your production-ready app to App Store

> **Do not proceed** if you won't comply with the license agreement or you can't pay the yearly membership fee
>
> **WARNING**: Only publish your app to App Store when production-ready. If not yet, try deploying to [TestFlight](https://testflight.apple.com) first.

This option is recommended, but you need to have an Apple ID protected by 2-factor authentication and:

- provide basic personal information about yourself if enrolling as an individual
- if enrolling as an organization, requires:

  - your org's D-U-N-S number (New to D-U-N-S numbers? See [this help center article](https://developer.apple.com/support/D-U-N-S/) to get started)
  - has a legal entity status (not for DBAs, fictitious businesses, trade names, or branches)
  - the person who enrolling your org must have the legal authority to fill and sign agreements with Apple and other companies.
  - a public viewable website associated with your org
- prepare 99 USD (or local equivalent in your country after conversion) for the yearly membership fee.

For FAQs about enrolling in Apple Developer Program, see https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment. To get started, visit [enrollment page](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/), click **Start Your Enrollment** when compliance checks are done (I mean when you met the requirements above), sign in your Apple ID and start filling up paperwork.

> **IMPORTANT**: Read the [license agreement](https://developer.apple.com/terms/) first with your org's legal department or your attorney if enrolling as an individual. You must not only read it but also understand it.

When your app is published, then add your app and configure it as usual.

### Troubleshooting Link doesn't work in Safari

> **QUICK NOTE**: Like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59066238/11934990), you need to add this code to your the configuration file, like this:
>
> ```
> {"applinks": {
>   "apps":[],
>   "details":[{
>       "appID":"495878282985.madebythepinsteam.publicofficialapp", // Change it with your Apple Store ID.
>       "paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}
>   ]}
> }
> ```
>
> If the code above is wrong, feel free to test and edit.

- Check whether you follow the instructions set herein.
- If the instructions I gave are not enough, then look [around the internet for troubleshooting](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=link+not+working+in+safari&atb=v196-3&ia=web). Maybe you read some docs as a refresher. The documentation is the first place to look around for answers.
- Check whether your iOS device is up-to-date. If the issue was the OS itself, check the app code and debug.
- Test the app again. If not works, repeat the steps above until the problem solved.

Comment: hello i have edit my question please help me if you can as now i am able to redirect on my debug applicaton but when its redirect on safari directly through appstore but when i am open that link on chrome its redirect to my application now i want to redirect to my app using safari also how to do this....

Comment: Hi, @AkashRaghani ! The Objective-C code is provided for this answer. Maybe you missed it or forgot to read the full text, is it?

Comment: Hi, Andrei i have edited my question as before i was not able to redirect on application but now I am able to redirect app while clicking on link but it's redirect on safari and not working.So every time i have to copy that link and open into google chrome.....so my question is why it is not working in safari directly???

Answer (score 1):

I assume you forgotten to do some configuration in Firebase. In my case during development, I just put a placeholder AppStore ID in my Firebase project. E.g. `1234567890` and my Team ID, which makes dynamic links in debug builds possible.

I can't find the original text, but I remember that Firebase tells you that you need to insert a Team ID and AppStore ID to make dynamic links to work.

Once you created the dynamic link, you need to check the `apple-app-site-association` endpoint of your dynamic link. E.g.

https://yourveryown.page.link/apple-app-site-association

The result must be something like this (it might take some time to refresh):

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"YOURTEAMID.com.yourcompany.app","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}
```

So to summarize:

- Make sure that you have insert some Appstore ID;
- Make sure the Team ID is properly set and the same ID is being used during compilation of your app;

[image]

Comment: my concern is that continueUserActivity method is not called can you please help me what is my problem

Comment: @AkashRaghani did you add the `GoogleService-Info.plist` to your project? And did you add the Firebase url in the Info.plist's `CFBundleURLSchemes`?

Comment: yes google info.plist  CFBundleURLSchemes I didn't get you

Comment: @AkashRaghani do you have a SceneDelegate? Try calling the new method mentioned here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59483485/7826293). Only being called if the app is running in background already.

Comment: "I remember that Firebase tells you that you need to insert a Team ID and AppStore ID to make dynamic links to work" - you are most likely referring to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLBjAg6HvG0&t=204s).

Comment: You need to add the proper url in your `Info.plist` in section `CFBundleURLSchemes`.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on Firebase dynamic links and this is what helped me.

**Solution:**

As you do not have the release app on app-store, this means you can redirect to

1. A webpage, or a,
2. A debug app (which is what you want).

For the second option,
You need to add your debug app to Firebase console so that you can select your debug app to open when clicked on a dynamic link like this:

[image: Firebase Dynamic links]

If you want to know how to add another app to your firebase console, click here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

[image]

Comment: please give option for iOS Application

Comment: i have updated my question adding screenshot please check

Comment: yes i want this only i am tired now A debug app (which is what you want).

Comment: in the option where you select com.pdd, how many options are there?

Comment: I have added screenshot please check as that are the only options.

Comment: That means you need to add another iOS app with Debug build. Can you do that?

Just go on this link and add the debug iOS app on Appstore.

Comment: hello i have edit my question please help me if you can as now i am able to redirect on my debug applicaton but when its redirect on safari directly through appstore but when i am open that link on chrome its redirect to my application now i want to redirect to my app using safari also how to do this....